# Is it possible to use epoll to write fifo/pipe data to multiple reader in one thread?

Tags: linux, pipe, fifo, epoll

There is a publisher which writing data by many different fifos/pipes to other clients in my program.

I know that if I open a fifo with non-blocking flag to write, the open will return an `No such address or device` error.

If I remove the non-blocking flag, the open will be blocked, so just one pipe can be used. How can I solve this problem?

This is a related url, [When I try to open a fifo O_WRONLY I get a "No such device or address" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24972911/when-i-try-to-open-a-fifo-o-wronly-i-get-a-no-such-device-or-address-error). But no answer got there.

Comment: @shawn Yes, you are right. But in my program, the clients/readers are not always ready, they may open the read end anytime. But my publisher do not want to check the status (read end opened). Is there any notification for read end opened? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the only way to solve your problem is to include a timer based polling loop where you attempt to open each FIFO once a second or so. Make that part of your select/poll/epoll loop. You can stop doing it once all of them are open.

Comment: Thank you. I agree with you. Maybe this question has no answer.

Answer (score 0):

epoll only works with file descriptors, and you won't have a file descriptor until after a successful open. You may be able to work around the problem by first opening the fifo for reading. For example, modifying the sample program from the related question:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int fdread;
  char *fifoname = "my_fifo";
  mkfifo(fifoname, 0666);

  if ((fdread = open(fifoname, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK)) == -1) {
    perror("open read only");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  int fd;
  if ((fd = open(fifoname, O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK)) == -1) {
    perror("open write only");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  close(fd);
  close(fdread);
  printf("everything is fine\n");
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

This solves the immediate problem, but may or may not work with the rest of your design.